# Django images not displaying

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to give the users the ability to upload profile pictures and I have the Upload section working. Im running into issues when trying to display the picture in the template. Here is what I currently have:

Urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.ME    DIA_ROOT,}),
#other urls
);
```

Settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/bpurdy/socialCompromise/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Model:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    STATUS = Choices('active', 'disabled')
    GENDER_CHOICES = (('Male','M'), ('Female','F'),)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    photo = models.ImageField("Profile Pic", upload_to="images/profiles", blank = True, null = True)
    #Other user properties
```

Template: (Key is the user)

```
{%if key.profile.photo %}
    <img src="{{ key.profile.photo.url }}" alt="{{key.profile.photo.title}}">
{%endif%}
```

After the upload there is a file located in the /home/bpurdy/socialCompromise/media/images/profiles directory however when trying to render the page I get the following errors:

```
SERVER_IP_ADDRESS/media/images/profiles/Desert.jpg 404 (Not Found) And
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: SERVER_IP_ADDRESS/search/images/profiles/Desert.jpg".
```

And the image wont display.

Answer (score 1):

Try urls.py like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # urls
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and tell me how it works.

Comment: After making the change I'm still seeing the same errors in the console and the image is still not showing up.